# Angular 2 DOM adapter

Tags: angular, typeerror

Try to use DOM adapter like this:

```
import { DOM } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
DOM.addClass(DOM.query("body"), 'test');
```

But get an error

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: dom_adapter_1.DOM is null ...

in the generated code dom_adapter_1.DOM is null, but dom_adapter_1.default.DOM not null and work fine.

(angular2: "2.0.0-beta.8")

To workaround I added to `"angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts"` this func: `"export declare function DOM2(): DomAdapter;`", and simple implementation in angular.js (function DOM2(){ return this.default.DOM;})

now I use it like:

```
import { DOM2 } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
DOM2().addClass(DOM2().query("body"), 'test');
```

Comment: are you talking about [BrowswerDomAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html)?

Comment: yes. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely. But you can use `BroswerDomAdapter` like this. (Only if it helps you)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
//import { DOM } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <style>
      .test{
        color:green;
      }
    </style>
    <button (click)="add()">Add New Element</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
 dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
  constructor() { 
    this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
  }
  add(){
     this.dom.addClass(this.dom.query("button"),"test");
  }
}
```

***[working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9uTJjdsiraXhimewFRPl?p=preview)***

Comment: Please let me know if it is irrelevant of your question, I'd delete it now.

Comment: I think this is a good workaround but `DOM` should be initialized with the proper specialized DOM adapter automatically for the platform where the application runs (Server, Client, WebWorker)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with DOM in TypeScript https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904